# Cannot install react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Tags: git, react-native, github, npm

When running the following within Visual Studio Code:

```
npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```

The following error is thrown:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-navi@0.15.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/core@6.4.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/core
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/core@"^6.4.9" from @react-navigation/native@6.1.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!       peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.6.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!         @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.6.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.6.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.6.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-navi@0.15.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navi
npm ERR!   react-navi@"^0.15.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-navi@0.15.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navi
npm ERR!     react-navi@"^0.15.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
```

When running

`npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs` **--force**

or

`npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs` **--legacy-peer-deps**

The error changes to:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-navi@0.15.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/core@6.4.9
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-navigation/core
npm WARN     @react-navigation/core@"^6.4.9" from @react-navigation/native@6.1.7
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm WARN   16 more (@react-navigation/drawer, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-navi@0.15.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-navi
npm WARN   react-navi@"^0.15.0" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-navi@0.15.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-navi
npm WARN     react-navi@"^0.15.0" from the root project
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react-navigation/bottom-tabs.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Up to this point, have had no issue installing react native packages.

Any help is mighty appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react-navigation/bottom-tabs.git
```

Which means that git doesn't accept ssh links for the fetch of package install.

An SSH URL necessitates the presence of a public key for initial user authentication, followed by access to the repository (a given privilege due to its public nature).

You can setup npm to use **HTTPS URLs** instead of **SSH**:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Here you got more related information:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Or maybe you need to update npm to the *lastest version*:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: npm install npm@latest -g in the VSC terminal throws an error including:
'The operation was rejected by your operating system.
It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user'.
git config --global url."https://github.com/".  in VSC terminal throws:
'error: key does not contain variable name: url.https://github.com/.'
Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Ran the two git config commands together in the VSC terminal, restarted VSC, still get the same original error. Am I running these commands incorrectly?  Thanks

Comment: This could maybe sound foolish, but, did you have configurated your credentials into git? I mean, did you ran `git config --global user.name` and  `git config --global user.email`? 
Also, try to run both commands separatelly.

Comment: That was not an issue. To resolve, reinstalled VSC, went through the instillation process again of all the required packages using the official docs, and pulled my repository from git. I echo what others have said: the npm package management dependency resolution appears to be one of RN's weak points. Your thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I usually have problems like this when working in RN, what I do is patch the dependencies manually with [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) because of the problem of finding (unfortunelly) some dependencies already have no maintenance.

Comment: Juan, how much a problem is the package dependencies - have seen it mentioned as one of the disadvantages of RN versus Flutter. If you have used Flutter, would be interested to your your thoughts on which you prefer overall.

Comment: Honestly, I'm considering to learn Swift (cause I'm learning C) and forget about using React for native app development. I've no experience with Dart but Flutter could be an alternative to React Native of course.